# Spark-Streaming from an Actor

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, actor

I would like to have a consumer actor subscribe to a Kafka topic and stream data for further processing with Spark Streaming outside the consumer. Why an actor? Because I read that its supervisor strategy would be a great way to handle Kafka failures (e.g., restart on a failure).

I found two options:

- The Java [`KafkaConsumer`](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) class: its `poll()` method returns a `Map[String, Object]`. I would like a `DStream` to be returned just like `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` would, and I don't know how to fetch the stream from outside the actor.
- Extend the `ActorHelper` trait and use `actorStream()` like shown in this [example](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/getting-started-with-kafka-using-scala-kafka-client-and-akka). This latter option doesn't display a connection to a topic but to a socket.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For handling Kafka failures, I used the Apache Curator framework and the following workaround:

```
val client: CuratorFramework = ... // see docs
val zk: CuratorZookeeperClient = client.getZookeeperClient

/**
  * This method returns false if kafka or zookeeper is down.
  */ 
def isKafkaAvailable:Boolean = 
   Try {
      if (zk.isConnected) {
        val xs = client.getChildren.forPath("/brokers/ids")
        xs.size() > 0
      }
      else false
    }.getOrElse(false)
```

For consuming Kafka topics, I used the `com.softwaremill.reactivekafka` library. For example:

```
class KafkaConsumerActor extends Actor {
   val kafka = new ReactiveKafka()
   val config: ConsumerProperties[Array[Byte], Any] = ... // see docs

   override def preStart(): Unit = {
      super.preStart()

      val publisher = kafka.consume(config)
      Source.fromPublisher(publisher)
            .map(handleKafkaRecord)
            .to(Sink.ignore).run()
   }

   /**
     * This method will be invoked when any kafka records will happen.
     */
   def handleKafkaRecord(r: ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Any]) = {
      // handle record
   }
}
```